# Chef quote syntax vs :xxx syntax

Tags: chef-infra

I'm new to Chef and I saw people do this: `node[:abc][:def]` and some times `node['abc']['def']`. I just don't know the differences even thought I assume it's the same. Best practice, which one I should use?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby, `:thing` is symbol. `'thing'` is a string. There are subtle difference in their behavior. The best resource I found on the subject is [this article](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/).

In general, it's a matter of preference. It actually [used to be a rule in Foodcritic](https://github.com/acrmp/foodcritic/pull/97), but there was a lot of contention and it was removed. Under the hood, Chef actually uses a Mash, so it doesn't matter what you use. It's really a matter of preference.

The only caveat is interpolation. While it's possible to interpolate with a symbol, it's far less common. For that reason, you'll often see strings as the more common key choice.